# react parent send "event" to child

Tags: reactjs

I am running some tests with react to find out a way for a parent to send an "event" to a child component. In the test application, the parent (CounterController) has a button. When the button is clicked, the parent shall send a reset "event" to the child (Counter) to reset the current count. Like below.

[image: The counter app UI]

I am new to react, and can not find a way to dispatch/receive events or messages between components. I had a thought to mark the "reset" request as a "state" in the parent, then pass it to the child through props. Then the child clear the "reset" state, through a callback function, to avoid repeating "reset" requests. However, I got the code run into an infinite loop. Here are my codes.

The parent component - CounterController
[image: the parent]
The child component - Counter
[image: the child]
the error logs

[image: error logs]

I do not feel that I am using react the right way, by asking the child to do something from the parent. Anyway, any idea about how to implement this app in react? How should the data flow be built correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I developed a new solution and implemented the logic. In the new solution, I managed the count value in the parent (CounterController) and build interfaces for increment and reset the count value in the parent as well. Then count value and increment interface are sent to the child through props for display and the ++ button. Problem solved, but not sure if this is how should I think in react.

Comment: It’s a good solution, that’s what i suggest on answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move up the counter state on the parent ‘CounterController’
and then you pass the counter and setCounter as props to ‘Counter’

You don’t need ‘reset’ state

Comment: Thanks. so my second solution is the right way to think in react? This way I am feeling that the react components are just the "view" or "presentation layer" of the app. Because the controls and data are stored outside the components.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my thoughts about using react (as a beginner), and my solution to the app.

1. treat the react components as the "view" of the application, and maintain the data and controls in the hooks.
2. create a custom hook to wrap up all data and controls.
3. create an instance of the custom hook in the top component - display the data in HTML elements and bound controls to buttons to build the app UI

Here are my codes for this simple UI

UI

[image]

**useCounter hook**

[image]

**counterController component**

[image]

**counter component**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Move "count" state from child component (Counter) to parent
   component (CounterController).
2. Pass count state as prop to child component.
3. Pass increment and decrement methods from parent to child component through props.

---

**Note: Remove reset state, it's not required anymore.**

---

Sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-platform-vo4qtv?file=/src/CountController.js